# Developing Web Application via React JS - httpSter or best way?

Tags: react-native

We are planning to develop a web application and use react native framework.

We are bundle all the files inside a folder and start httpster to run the web-application.

Is that is the only way to run react native web apps or any other way?

for example, tomcat is a web app server and can we use the same and play framework has its own server and can be just run react files on play

In pre-requisites it says we just need the react js libraries.

Please let me know in detail.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React Native is used for native mobile development.

For a webapp you can just use regular react.

https://facebook.github.io/react/

Comment: Is regular react is pluggable and works in any app server - tomcat, jboss, play framework etc., ? any constraint. for example play is non-blocking IO which differs from tomcat.